# Can I install Android on my HTC Touch HD?

Tags: windows-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have an HTC Touch HD running Windows Mobile 6.1. Is it possible to run Android on my phone instead of Windows Mobile?

If so, how do I install Android and will it be possible to revert to Windows Mobile if the need should arise?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible with a custom build of the Android operating system, available from the [XDA Developers Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=577).

The latest version available as of January 2011 is Android 2.2 and there are download, installation, and troubleshooting instructions in this **[XDA Developers forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=732362)**.